# create edge list from select on self join

Tags: sql, oracle, graph

I'm try to create an un-directed edge list from a table of users and the associated product they bought. To do this I am doing a self join on the table based on the product in order to capture users who are connected by the fact they bought the same product. My problem with the query below is that it returns two records which are opposite of each other when I only want one of them. How can this be accomplished? I tried messing around with some analytic functions and was able to get my desired result but am wondering if there is a better way because this will be run on ~650 million records.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c248/22)

```
create table user_products as (
  select 'user1' usr, 'bananas' products from dual
  union
  select 'user2', 'bananas' from dual
  union
  select 'user3', 'pickles' from dual
  );

select t1.usr, t2.usr 
from user_products t1
inner join user_products t2
  on t1.products = t2.products
where t1.usr != t2.usr;
```

Query Results:

```
|   USR |   USR |
|-------|-------|
| user2 | user1 |
| user1 | user2 |
```

Desired Results:

```
|   USR |   USR |
|-------|-------|
| user1 | user2 |
```

Working via last_value function, but wondering if there is a better way?

```
select * from (
select usr userA, last_value(usr ignore nulls) over(partition by products order by products
rows between unbounded preceding and 1 preceding) userB from user_products)
where userB is not null;
```

Query Results:

```
| USERA | USERB |
|-------|-------|
| user2 | user1 |
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use `<` or `>` in the `join` condition instead of `!=`.

```
select t1.usr, t2.usr 
from user_products t1
inner join user_products t2
  on t1.products = t2.products
where t1.usr < t2.usr;
```